# preventing inherited variable labels in r

Tags: r, inheritance, label, hmisc

I have a file of 2,000 columns.  In order to help keep all these variables defined, I'd like to use labels and work package Hmisc.  So far, so good.  My problem: I can't stop any derived variable columns from inheriting the labels.

I don't want var2 to inherit the label from var1 in the assignment below.  Is there a way to deactivate this basic behavior in R?!

```
var1 <- 1:3
label(var1) <- "var one"
str(var1)

Classes 'labelled', 'integer'  atomic [1:3] 1 2 3
..- attr(*, "label")= chr "var one"

var2 <- var1+10
str(var2)

Classes 'labelled', 'integer'  atomic [1:3] 11 12 13
..- attr(*, "label")= chr "var one"
```

var2 should not be labelled "var one"!!!!

Comment: Please include your `library` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above example, why not just relabel var2 to something else?

```
library("Hmisc")

var1 <- 1:3
label(var1) <- "var one"
str(var1)

var2 <- var1+10
label(var2) <- "var two"
str(var2)
```